# C# How to copy multiple files using task

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

suppose my files name with path store in list and i want to use task lib to copy all those files stored in list from destination folder to target folder.

```
List<string> filename = new List<string>(Enumerable.Range(0,8).
Select(value=>"Z:\report_"+EndDate.Date.AddDays(value).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")+".csv"));
```

so filename variable has all files info which i have to copy. now tell me how i can use task to copy all files and also there will be one call back function which tell me when all files copying done. looking for fresh code.

this would be Disk bound operation and if i use task lib to copy multiple files simultaneously then process will be slower?

anyone can post some sample code to show how one can use task which will automatically loop in list where files with path are stored and using task lib to copy all files simultaneously from one folder to another folder.
thanks

Comment: Easiest would be `Parallel.ForEach()`

Comment: would u mind to post some sample code to copy multiple files simultaneously using `Parallel.ForEach()`

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, I merely posted that comment to give you something to research. A couple of google searches should give you some examples of how to use `Parallel.ForEach` and how to copy files.

Comment: got link to know several way to use TPL https://dotnetcodr.com/2014/01/01/5-ways-to-start-a-task-in-net-c/   http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/362996/Multi-core-programming-using-Task-Parallel-Library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good example of how to loop through multiple files in parallel using the parallel.foreach loop:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720(v=vs.110).aspx

The example does work to some bitmap files.  You would simply need to replace the logic in their lambda expression to copy the current file to where you want it to go.

Edit:  I threw together some simple sample code based on the example in the link above:

```
List<string> filename = new List<string>(Enumerable.Range(0, 8).Select(value => "Z:\report_" + EndDate.Date.AddDays(value).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + ".csv"));

String targetDirectoryPath = @"c:\my_target_folder\"; //TODO: Set this to your target directory.
bool allowOverwrites = false; //Set this to true if you want to allow overwriting of existing files!

Parallel.ForEach(filename, (currentFilePathToCopy) =>
{
    // The more computational work you do here, the greater 
    // the speedup compared to a sequential foreach loop.
    String currentFilename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(currentFilePathToCopy);


    string targetFilePath = targetDirectoryPath + currentFilename;

    try
    {
        System.IO.File.Copy(currentFilePathToCopy, targetFilePath, allowOverwrites);
    }
    catch (Exception caughtException)
    {
        //TODO: Handle copy error here!
    }                                
});
```

Comment: if i follow or use TPL to copy files instead of one-by-one file then it will be faster because file copy will be disk bound job not CPU bound i guess. please share your suggestion. thanks

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach` may create race condition when copying files. what u think?

Comment: If you make sure that you have no duplicate items in your file list, then you should be fine.  Per Microsoft: "Don't allow duplicate instances in parallel loops. If an object appears more than once in the input to a loop, it's possible that two parallel threads could update the object at the same time."  A race condition exists when two or more independent processes or threads attempt to modify a single resource.  So long you're not trying to copy the same file more than once, or copy 2 or more files to the same destination file, then you should be fine.